# Save PDF in a specific folder programmatically

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to get this program to save my pdf files in the same folder that the excel template is being saved in which is my Template Code folder. 
Here is the code that I have so far. The part where I am stuck is down at the bottom at "Dim Save Path.."

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
Sub SaveToPDF()

Dim fp As String
Dim fp1 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Max As Integer
Dim numprints As Integer
Dim fnum As String
Dim wb As Workbook

i = 1

fnum = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").Value

Worksheets("Printable").Activate
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'counting the number of pagebreaks to identify number of prints
Max = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count

numprints = Max / 2
k = 10

'to get the file name for each PDF and setting the folder to print
For j = 1 To numprints
    fp1 = CStr(fnum & " - " & (Replace(Sheets("Printable").Range("f" & k).Value, "/", "-")))
    fp = CStr("Q:\PATS\24-7\Partnership Accounting\2013\2013 TAX\2013 Clients\8392 - 8413 AAF Master Folder\PDF\" & fp1 & ".pdf")

' exports 2 pages at a time and creates a PDF, then loops
    wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fp, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False, From:=i, To:=i + 1

    i = i + 2
    k = k + 70
Next j
MsgBox ("Print to PDF Complete, Check if you have " & numprints & " PDF Files")



'save the pdf in the 8392-8413 Master Folder under the Template Code Folder


       Dim SaveName As String

       SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Text
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveName & ".xls"



Dim SavePath As String


SavePath = CStr("Q:\PATS\24-7\Partnership Accounting\2013\2013 TAX\2013 Clients\8392 - 8413 AAF Master Folder\Template Code" & fp1 & ".pdf")

            SavePath = wb.Path

            ChDir SavePath
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _ 
                 SavePath & "Form 8392-8413 - " & ".pdf" _
                , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True


End Sub
```

Comment: You have two assignments to `SavePath`, which one do you want to use?  Right now I can see why this is failing. If you remove `SavePath = wb.Path`, I think it should work. Let me know if it does not.

Comment: HI David. Thank you. I tried and will leave the [SavePath = wb.Path] out now. The PDF files are still saving in the wrong folder. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the location of the folder where they are being saved incorrectly?

Comment: i went into file
edit
preferences
security(enhanced)
un check the enable protected mode at start up
now if i make changes to a pdf, i can just hit the save button, and it will override and save the changes as normal. I I am not sure by unchecking this will do to the security of the document.. But so far it is working fine, but i have only made this change a couple days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Well first I see that you have two assignments to `SavePath` variable. First, `Cstr("Q...")`, and on the next line you are resetting it `wb.path`.  That is probably the source of your error.

I think you do not need this line, it looks like it was leftover from debugging because this is a *full filename + path*.

If you want to use this line:

```
SavePath = CStr("Q:\PATS\24-7\Partnership Accounting\2013\2013 TAX\2013 Clients\8392 - 8413 AAF Master Folder\Template Code" & fp1 & ".pdf")
```

Then you **must delete this line**:

```
SavePath = wb.Path
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `wb.Path` to concatenate within the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method, then the error is this: `wb.Path` will not end in a path separator, and so that will raise an error when you try to save.

To fix it, try:

```
SavePath = wb.Path
If Not Right(SavePath,1) = Application.PathSeparator Then 
    SavePath = SavePath & Application.PathSeparator
End If
```